# flask cli can't locate the script manage.py

Tags: python, flask, flask-cli

my flask app is a package named `app` located at `/Users/gexinjie/Codes/MyProject/xinnjie_blog`

the file tree is like this

```
xinnjie_blog
├── app
|   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── exceptions.py
│   ├── model.py
│   ├── model_sqlalchemy.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── util.py
│   └── views
├── manage.py
```

I export it as `PATHONPATH`, so `manage.py` can import `app`

```
echo $PATHONPATH
/Users/gexinjie/Codes/MyProject/xinnjie_blog
```

and export `FLASK_APP`

```
echo $FLASK_APP
manage.py
```

current dir is `/Users/gexinjie/Codes/MyProject/xinnjie_blog`

```
pwd
/Users/gexinjie/Codes/MyProject/xinnjie_blog
```

here is the `manage.py`

```
import click
from app import create_app

app = create_app('development')

@app.cli.command()
def initdb():
    click.echo('Init the db...')
```

here is `app.__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from .model_sqlalchemy import db

def create_app(config_name='default'):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...   # init
    return app
```

but then if I execute `flask initdb`, I get this error:

```
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Error: No such command "initdb".
```

and if I execute `flask run`, I get

```
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

 Error: The file/path provided (manage) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

why manage.py is not found? And how can I fix it.
(actually it worked well when `manage.py` have flask app in itself )

```
# manage.py
# this work well
app = Flask(__name__)  # not app = create_app('development')
```

Thank you

Comment: Is `app` a file or a directory? Can you post its full contents?

Comment: @NathanWailes `app` is a directory. I have posted its full content.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `app/__init__.py`?

Comment: @NathanWailes I have posted `__init__.py`

Comment: Are you using Linux as your OS or Windows?

Comment: @NathanWailes these codes run on mac os. I think it has some problem during importing .because when manage.py initializes  a Flask instance by itself, the script works well.However, there is so little error informattion given by flask command tool.

Comment: what does `flask --help` get you? Also I am assuming you have `app.run()` at the bottom of manage.py under the `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Also I would try doing the absolute path so `export FLASK_APP=$(pwd)/manage.py`

Comment: @Adam add `app.run()` after `if __name__ == '__main__'` does not help, it makes the script run the flask app directly. But I tried adding `app.cli() `, then it works partially  after I executed `python manage.py `(`run` does't exist). `flask` command still can't find `manage.py`.(I tried absolute path)

Comment: I posted an answer but realized it wasn't correct when tried it on an app of mine. Here is my [code](https://hastebin.com/quyafecaqa.py) and it works. I honestly don't know whats up with yours. Are you using any type of virtual environment?

Comment: @Adam Thanks to your advice! That remind me to check flask version. I test `manage.py` all the time on Pycharm command tool, and in that tool `flask` is installed by Anaconda's python 3.6. I usually use python3.5 on terminal. So `flask` may lack some extensions and cause the problem.(though I'm not sure).after I uninstalled Anaconda, every thing goes well now.

Comment: @Adam by the way, the error message given by `flask` command tool is so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @Adam, This problem was solved after I uninstall Anaconda.

Because all the time I tested `manage.py` on Pycharm command tool, and that `flask` was installed by Anaconda(python version 3.6), it may lack some extensions(usually I use python3.5 on terminal).So I think the problem occur during importing.

The flask command tool complain about 'can't locate the app', but the real problem is import error.So that is so confusing.

---

"universal" solution:

So when if you come to this kind of problem like I do, I suggest you first **check the location of your app**(try both relative path and absolute path), relative path may cause the locate problem when you are not at the right working directory.So absolute path is recommend.

If every thing about path went well, then make sure that **all the packages required by your app is installed and can be imported**. if you are using some type of virtual environment or something like that (In my case, I use the other version of python lacking some flask extensions), it may be the import error makes `flask` complain.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: If you are using PyCharm I would create a virtualenv for every project and select the system installed interpreter as your base and then use the terminal inside PyCharm to do any commands.